# Add user's secondary values (Employee Details) such as Title to Google Directory

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have wrote a script that successfully takes a Google Sheet full of User information and adds them to our Google Domain. I however can't seem to figure out how to add certain secondary values that are specific to our org. Some of the values are Employee ID, Title, (These are found under additional info when adding user) etc... I've been racking my brain all day trying different things, figured I'd ask here after searching for other posts that didn't quite answer the question

```
function AddUsers() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('xxxxx');
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var lastName = data[i][0];
  var firstName = data[i][1];
  var email = data[i][2];
  var password = data[i][3];
  var changePass = data[i][4];
  var orgPath = data[i][5];
  var groupEmail = data[i][6];
  var role = data[i][7];


var user = {
  "name" : {
    "givenName" : firstName,
    "familyName" : lastName
  }, 
  "primaryEmail": email,
  "password": password,
  "changePasswordAtNextLogin": changePass,
  "orgUnitPath": orgPath
};

AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);

var group = {
  "email": email,
  "role":role,
};

AdminDirectory.Members.insert(group, groupEmail);

};
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by running a get query on a user, which Google returns all values with the proper titles, this gave me the format that I needed to add the values. It was a combination of organizations[] and exterenalID[].

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could set them using [Custom User Fields](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas). See field `customSchemas` from the [users resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource).

Comment: Well we already have a schema in place, a default one of "Employee Details". However when I follow that syntax I just get 400 error for Invalid Input: [Employee Details]

Comment: I'm glad you solved the issue. Would you mind adding the `user` object in your answer above?

Comment: The user objects were `"externalIds":[ {"value":"xxxx", "type":"xxxxx"}]` and I also had some fields in `"organizations":[{"title":"xxxx", "primary":"true", "customType":"", "description": "xxxxx"}]`